# How to run Wordpress admin on a site subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm new with WordPress, trying to map the wp-admin to a subdomain:

instead of: www.mydomain.net/wp-admin I would like: admin.mydomain.net

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is specific to WordPress and not about WordPress development.

Comment: It's not really possible to move the admin section to a subdomain without making a ton of modifications to WordPress itself. And then you'd need to worry about upgrades as these would undo any changes made to core files. Not really worth the trouble, just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to try [this method of masking the admin URL by TricksPanda](https://trickspanda.com/hide-wordpress-admin-url/).  I haven't tried this with a subdomain, but if that implementation doesn't work, perhaps just a modified admin URL will work for your implementation as outlined in that post (instead of the full-on subdomain).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a config file with the site name as the name, eg admin.mydomain.net and set the server_name in the config file to admin.mydomain.net and then point the root to wherever you have put the wordpress installation.